# Delete lines in blocklist file, where the end of those lines match an entry from an allowlist file (Using Dnsmasq syntax)

Tags: awk

This is a modification of a question I've previously asked, this time to account for Dnsmasq syntax in the blocklist.  I'm trying to delete lines in an blocklist file, but only if the end of the blocklist line matches an entry in an allowlist file.  Subdomain blocklist entries should therefore also be removed.  Trying to stick to using awk since that package is included in OpenWRT, as apposed to eg gawk which is available, but is an additional download.

**Blocklist file (with dnsmasq style syntax)**

```
local=/randomsites.com/
local=/calendar.google.com/
local=/google.com/
local=/google.com.fake.com/
local=/fakegoogle.com/
```

**Allowlist file**

```
google.com
```

**Desire output to new_blocklist**

```
local=/randomsites.com/
local=/google.com.fake.com/
local=/fakegoogle.com/
```

Below is where I've tried to modify a solution from a previous question I asked, but this time to account for dnsmasq syntax in the blocklist.  This method was extremely fast to process large lists (~300k lines in around 10 seconds on dual core router), which is especially useful for lower powered routers.

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="." }
NR==FNR {
    allow[$0"/"]
    next
}
{
    addr = $NF
    for ( i=NF-1; i>=1; i-- ) {
        addr = $i FS addr
        if ( substr(addr,8) in allow ) {
            next
        }
    }
}
{ print }
```

`awk -f tst.awk allow block` is producing output:

```
local=/randomsites.com/
local=/calendar.google.com/
local=/google.com.fake.com/
local=/fakegoogle.com/
```

And so is not removing the local=/calendar.google.com/ entry as desired.

The exact previous solution by Ed Morton which worked perfectly for a blocklist of eg google.com, calendar.google.com (ie without the dnsmasq syntax of local=/...../) was:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="." }
NR==FNR {
    allow[$0]
    next
}
{
    addr = $NF
    for ( i=NF-1; i>=1; i-- ) {
        addr = $i FS addr
        if ( addr in allow ) {
            next
        }
    }
}
{ print }
```

I realise I haven't modified this solution correctly, but I have tried quite a lot time/reading to at least try and solve myself first.

**REPORTING ON SOLUTIONS BELOW**

Both @markp-fuso and @Ed Morton (author of original awk solution exc dnsmasq syntax) solutions are producing exactly the same, and correct, result.  Now the interesting part is the run-times of both solutions on a netgear r7800 openwrt router, which is a dual core 2015 CPU.  Multiple runs on each produced consistent runs times:

@markp-fuso solution:

```
300k lines blocklist, 13 lines allowlist = 23.3 seconds
300k lines blocklist, 300k lines allowlist = 21.5 seconds
```

@Ed Morton solution:

```
300k lines blocklist, 13 lines allowlist = 47.4 seconds
300k lines blocklist, 300k lines allowlist = 46
```

To note, both solutions have a faster runtime with the larger allowlist!

Thankyou both!  This is really great, and a big contribution to a little project we have going for OpenWRT to block ads on router.  Please delete link if not allowed here:

```
https://forum.openwrt.org/t/adblock-lean-set-up-adblock-using-dnsmasq-blocklist/157076/35
```

Comment: Another approach with GNU grep, sed and bash: `grep -vwf <(sed 's|$|/|' allow) block`

Comment: This looks like a really elegant solution and I want to experiment with it more.  This command is returning rep: /dev/fd/64: No such file or directory.  It might be a limitation of the grep included in OpenWRT.  I'll report back if I do get this to work.  Thanks!

Comment: @Cyrus I think that's a good idea but that grep command will treat all `.`s in the allow list as regexp metachars so it'll produce false matches, you'd need to add `-F` to avoid that.

Comment: @Wizballs try `tmp=$(mktemp) && { sed 's|$|/|' allow > "$tmp" && grep -vwFf "$tmp" block; rm -f "$tmp"; }`

Comment: @EdMorton this in itself has some interesting results.  For a blocklist of 300k lines, 13 allow lines was 1.7 seconds!  I mean I wasn't even ready to stop the clock.  Then for 500 allow lines 20.6 seconds.  1000 allow lines 40.4 seconds, so it appears runtime scales up linearly.  So this looks like a good solution if allowlist is under 500 lines, which I suspect the majority of use cases would be.

Answer (score 2):

One idea for modifying the answer to OP's previous question:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN   { FS="/" }                       # split on "/"
NR==FNR { allow[$0]; next }
        { n=split($2,arr,".")            # further split on "."

          # process as with answer to previous question

          addr = arr[n]
          for ( i=n-1; i>=1; i-- ) {
              addr = arr[i] "." addr
              if ( addr in allow )
                 next
          }
        }
1                                        # print current line; behaves identically to "{ print }"
```

**NOTE:** by using `FS="/"` and then referencing `$2` we are stripping off the `local=/` and (trailing) `/`

Taking for a test drive:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk allow block
local=/randomsites.com/
local=/google.com.fake.com/
local=/fakegoogle.com/
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="." }
NR==FNR {
    allow[$0]
    next
}
{
    orig = $0
    gsub("^local=/|/$","")
    addr = $NF
    for ( i=NF-1; i>=1; i-- ) {
        addr = $i FS addr
        if ( addr in allow ) {
            next
        }
    }
}
{ print orig }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk allowlist blocklist
local=/randomsites.com/
local=/google.com.fake.com/
local=/fakegoogle.com/
```

Answer (score 1):

In your specific case you could also use `grep`. If you have the contents of allow list, you can simply use `grep -v` with the pattern, e.g.

```bash
grep -v '\([.]\|/\)google.com/$' blocklist
```

If `allowlist` contains a single entry as shown, then in bash you could do:

```bash
grep -v '\([.]\|/\)'"$(<allowlist)"'/$' blocklist
```

And if you are using POSIX shell, then you could combine `read -r` and build the pattern from the single entry in `allowlist`, e.g.

```bash
read -r match <allowlist
pattern="\([.]\|/\)$match/\$"
grep -v "$pattern" blocklist
```

**Example Use/Output**

All above provide the same output with the contents in `allowlist` and `blocklist` as you show, e.g.

```
$ grep -v '\([.]\|/\)'"$(<allowlist)"'/$' blocklist
local=/randomsites.com/
local=/google.com.fake.com/
local=/fakegoogle.com/
```

Note: if `allowlist` contains multiple entries, then you would need to use `readarray -t` in bash to fill an indexed array with the contents and build your pattern from there. In POSIX shell you would just loop `while read -r match; do ... done < allowlist`.

`grep` just provides another approach. With a single entry in `allowlist` there would be little, if any, difference in efficiency between the use of `awk` and `grep`. If however `allowlist` contains multiple entries, then `awk` would provide a better solution avoiding the subshells created with multiple calls to `grep`. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: The intention is to have any number of allowlist entries desired.  I really should have included a few extra dummy lines in the allowlist file!  This is my fault, I know what I wanted and spent ages typing the question then leave out a piece of the puzzle lol.  However, this answer perfectly demonstrates the use case scenario between awk or grep.  Thankyou so much!

Comment: No worries, that's why I added the note at the end. I felt fairly sure you would want more than one entry in the `allowlist` file -- in which case, the `awk` solution is the way to go. Otherwise you will simply spawn a separate subshell for each call to `grep` with each entry.

Comment: You'd have to escape every `.` in allowlist to avoid false matches.

Comment: Ah yes, that too! Good catch Ed. Thank you!